# Get column after group by lastest date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Please help me to get table 2 from table 1
[image]

Comment: can you pls put more details on this question? Images are not always a good idea.

Comment: The results make no sense.  Why would you want the *second* value for the first code?

Comment: In group that code1 = 1, i have 4 records, then I group and count it equal 4, in 4 records, i will choose the record that has date is latest, it is 16/2 => code2 is BBBBB

Comment: the latest date for code1 is 20/2 and the latest date for code2 is 21/1 please re-look at your image

Answer (score 0):

A simple summarisation can be achieved using `GROUP BY`

```
select
      code1
    , max(code2)  as code2
    , count(*)    as times
    , max(`date`) as max_dt
from table1
group by
     code1
```

However the result is different to the image:

```
+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| code1 | code2 | times |   max_dt   |
+-------+-------+-------+------------+
|     1 | D     |     4 | 2020-02-21 |
|     2 | NNNN  |     2 | 2021-01-21 |
+-------+-------+-------+------------+
```

Note:

1. The maximum of code2 may not be what you expect it to be. e.g. "D" is after "BBBBB" as the data is alphabetical. not based on length of string.
2. maximum of date for code1 isn't 16/2
3. I would not recommend naming any column "date" as it is usually a reserved word and can cause difficulties when developing queries.

for MySQL prior to version 8 a technique to get "the most recent" row may be used as follows:

```
SELECT code1, code2, `date`
    , (select count(*) from mytable t2 where d.code1 = t2.code1) as times
FROM (
        SELECT
              @row_num :=IF(@prev_value = t.code1, @row_num + 1, 1) AS rn
            , t.code1
            , t.code2
            , t.`date`
            , @prev_value := t.code1
        FROM mytable t
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
        ORDER BY
              t.code1
            , t.`date` DESC
    ) as d
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Or, for MySQL version 8 or later it is possible to use a much simpler query as there are windowing functions available through the `over()` clause:

```
SELECT code1, code2, `date`, times
FROM (
        SELECT
              row_number() over(partition by t.code1
                                order by t.`date` DESC) AS rn
            , t.code1
            , t.code2
            , t.`date`
            , count(*) over(partition by t.code1) as times
        FROM mytable t
    ) as d
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

The results of the 2nd and 3rd queries are the same:

```
+-------+-------+------------+-------+
| code1 | code2 |    date    | times |
+-------+-------+------------+-------+
|     1 | D     | 2020-02-21 |     4 |
|     2 | NNNN  | 2021-01-21 |     2 |
+-------+-------+------------+-------+
```

*solution demonstrated at db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7081c77912fdaa995a562012df86ee7e)*

Comment: It means I wanna get code2 that has date is latest in the group

Comment: these are the sort of facts that should be explained in your question! We cannot guess what is in your mind. However, please note the latest date in the group for code1=1 is not 16/2. Also: **What version of MySQL?** This is important

Comment: I have added 2 variants that get the rows associated with "the lastest date" for each code1, but again the results differ because **the latest date for code1 is NOT 16/2**